# Setting XValue in Excel VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have problem with setting `XValue` in my Chart. I have a multiple columns (dynamic count) so I generate `Range` text:

```
B8:E8;B10:E10;B12:E12;B14:E14;B16:E16
```

Then I set it to the chart:

```
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).chart.SetSourceData(Source:=ExcelSheet.Range(graf))
```

But then I have XValues like '1 2 3 4'

I want to set (generated) XValues like

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        With ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).chart.SeriesCollection(i)
            .Name = names(i - 1)
            .XValues = CStr(2010 + i)
        End With
    Next
```

But only first `XValue` is set. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now,

The thing was that there is only one series set with `;`

I needed to set `XValues` as

```
XVal &= ';' & CStr(2010 + i)
```

resulting in

```
2011;2012;2013;2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for info:

there is an another way using dynamic charts. For this aproach, see

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/dynamic_charts/index.html

Answer (score -1):

```
            chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).xvalues = "={""OCt"",""Nov"",""Dec"",""Jan"", ""Feb"", ""Mar"", ""Apr"", ""May"" , ""Jun"", ""Jul"", ""Aug"", ""Sep""}" '"=Hour!$F$2,Hour!$I$2,Hour!$L$2,Hour!$O$2,Hour!$R$2,Hour!$U$2,Hour!$X$2,Hour!$AA$2,Hour!$AD$2,Hour!$AG$2,Hour!$AJ$2,Hour!$AM$2"
```

> The Values Can Be Taken From Cell